# Styling input placeholder CSS within dev tools

Tags: html, css, textfield, placeholder

I know how to style the CSS of placeholder text/background/font-size etc across browsers with each browser's specified pseudo classes. However I cannot style them within the browser with dev tools and have not found an answer to whether this is even possible.

I'd love to work with placeholder styles without a trial and error workflow.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is possible in Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox.

In Chrome, go to the Dev Tools Settings (the gear icon in the top right) and under General|Elements turn on "Show user agent shadow DOM". In Edge and Opera it's under *Settings > Preferences > Elements > Show user agent shadow DOM*.

[image: Chrome Settings]

Now go inspect your text box. There should now be an arrow next to the input element.

Expand that and select `<div psuedo="-webkit-input-placeholder" id="placeholder" style="visibility: visible; text-overflow: clip;">`.

Your classes that you are using to modify the placeholder should show up in the style pane.

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

In Firefox, the style is shown by default in the Inspector tab, under "Pseudo-elements" (`::placeholder`).